# MacBook Pro Retina Mid 2014 shuts down randomly

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake, power, shutdown

For a while now, my Mid-2014 MacBook Pro Retina has been shutting down/sleeping randomly (without notifying me) while on battery power. After it shuts down, if I try to turn it on it asks me to plug it into the charger as if it was out of power. Once I plug it, I can turn it on normally and continue using it with the battery for some more hours (or until it happens again). The capacity of the battery is still quite good, actually.

Reading other similar questions, I think that the battery might be unable to sustain peak power and I will need to replace it. It would make sense because it usually happens when I hear the CPU fans running or I open many different apps in a short period of time. But, as I have seen that there are many possible causes for this issue (and the capacity is still good) I would like to confirm that this is the cause and not something else. Is there a log or something that could help me confirm this?

**SOME MORE INFO:**

Info about battery:

```
  Full capacity (mAh):  5616
Status:
  Cycles:   1793
  Condition:    Repair recommended
  Amps (mA):    1606
  Volts (mV):   11844
```

When I run

```
log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"' --last 24h
```

I get this... which I don't understand because it shows the code 5 which corresponds to Correct Shutdown (I filtered a case where the MacBook shut down the way I mentioned):

```
Filtering the log data using "composedMessage CONTAINS "Previous shutdown cause""
Skipping info and debug messages, pass --info and/or --debug to include.
Timestamp                       Thread     Type        Activity             PID    TTL
2023-01-19 11:53:45.010475+0100 0x1bf0f    Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Log      - Default:          4, Info:                0, Debug:             0, Error:          0, Fault:          0
Activity - Create:           0, Transition:          0, Actions:           0
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: A [shutdown code of “5” means it shutdown cleanly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/273084/119271). Your battery ran out of juice and the Mac acted appropriately;  turning off to save your data.

Comment: Also see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/391306/119271,  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/325796/119271,  and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/274122/119271

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely likely that a 9-year-old battery with nearly 1800 cycles would need to be replaced, particularly if it powers off randomly.

Failing batteries also don't always report accurate information.

Apple considers your battery 'consumed' when it has lost 80% of its capacity, or after 1000 cycles, at which point it becomes eligible for replacement.

You could get a bit more info from an app like [CoconutBattery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/), but I don't think you need to look for alternative explanations.

IMO, a battery replacement is well worth it, and will give your Mac a new lease of life.